# Unable to load modules in Powershell on Unix

Tags: macos, powershell, powershell-core

**EDIT:** There seems to be an issue with the unix implementation, which is not surprising, given that it is an alpha build still. See [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2677) for more info.

---

I have been having a lot of fun trying out Powershell on my Mac, and know I decided to try out making a simple module and import it. I am running the latest build (6, alpha, release 12). I consistently failed at importing it:

```
cat ./Foo/Foo.psm1
function Foo {
    param()
    }
    {
        Write-Output "foo says hi"
    }
}

cat ./foo-test.ps1

# add the current directory as a module dir
$env:PSModulePath = "/Users/john.doe/scripts/test"
Import-Module Foo


Import-Module : The specified module 'Foo' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At /Users/john.doe/scripts/test/foo.ps1:3 char:1
+ Import-Module Foo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Foo:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I then tried importing the module on Windows. It worked instantly:

```
PS C:\GitHub> $env:PSModulePath="C:\Github\"
PS C:\GitHub> Import-Module Foo
PS C:\GitHub> start
```

(Yes, I also tried doing it in the shell on Mac, still no go).

So I am wondering if modules are not supported yet on Mac, or if I am doing something wrong here?

Comment: The path provided isn't finding the file where it should be.  Hence, `no valid module file was found in any module directory.`

Comment: I know that... It says so. But why? And how do I correct it?

Comment: @gravity, that is not the case. You do not add the module path the psmodulepath. you add the path where the module(s) are residing. after running some tests on windows, it turned out to work perfectly there. so this is basically a bug in the unix implementation, and I posted bug issue on the microsoft bug tracker for powershell. See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2677 for details. Closing the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The module path variable should be written in uppercase!**

Instead of `$env:PsModulePath`, which would be correct on Windows (and is written like that in many articles by Microsoft) you need to start writing it in uppercase for your scripts to be cross-platform compatible: `$env:PSMODULEPATH`.

See [this issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2677) for more info. I made [this repo](https://github.com/fatso83/powershell-module-test) to demonstrate module loading that works in all platforms. Check it out if you are having problems.

**edit**: substituted a dot for colon in the env variable, as this is supposedly "more correct"